Eigenvalue problems $y''(x) + λy(x) = 0, 1 < x < 2, y(1) = y'(2) = 0$
Consider the eigenvalue problem $y''(x) + λy(x) = 0, 1 < x < 2, y(1) = y'(2) = 0$. Given the fact that its eigenvalues are positive, find all eigenvalues $λ_n$ and the corresponding eigenfunctions $y_n(x)$.
I have only learnt to do this with problems where I have values of angles given, I'm stuck on this, I know we have to write a formula for $y$ and then input the values of 1 and 2 in place of $x$ that will give us equations, but don't know how to do it with these equations.

"will give us equations, but don't know how to do it with these equations": which ones? those that your work "will give us", or those formulating the problem?

"I have only learnt to do this with problems where I have values of angles given": what do you mean?

"Given the fact that its eigenvalues...": I guess which operator is "it", but do you? (Btw, the eigenvalues of my operator are not all positive).

Solve $y''+\mu^2y=0$ as usual (you should have inserted such an attempt in your question, and explained where you were stuck): $$y=a\cos(\mu x)+b\sin(\mu x).$$ When substituting in $y(1)=y'(2)=0$, you find that such non-zero functions $y$ exist iff $\cos\mu=0$, and are then given by $y=a\cos(\mu x).$

You probably learned how to solve this in differential equations class, Calculus II or whatever you called it.  But, it seems unfamiliar in the setting of linear algebra.
So, how would you solve this in a calculus class with no linear algebra knowledge?
This is linear algebra class, but allow yourself to leverage some of that calculus knowledge.
The derivative is a linear operator, as is the second derivative.
What are the eigenfunctions of the derivative operator?
The functions such that $\frac {d}{dx} f(x) = \lambda f(x)$ are of the form $e^{\lambda x}$
What are the eigenfunctions of the second derivative operator?
Functions such that $\frac {d^2}{dx^2} f(x) = \lambda f(x)$ are of the form $e^{\sqrt {\lambda} x}$ and $e^{-\sqrt {\lambda} x}$ if $\lambda > 0$ or $\sin \sqrt {|\lambda|} x$ and $\cos \sqrt {|\lambda|} x$ if $\lambda < 0$
I suppose I should point out that $\cosh \sqrt {\lambda} x$ and $\sinh \sqrt \lambda x$ are also eigenfunctions, but they are linear combinations of $e^{\sqrt {\lambda} x}$ and $e^{-\sqrt {\lambda}}x$
And, a $\sin$ function with a phase shift is a linear combination of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions with the same period.
Then we must find which of these solves the initial values.
You will never find a combination of exponentials that cross the x-axis twice, which means the trigonometric functions are the place to look.
I think the $\sin$ function with phase shift is going to win.
$y(1) = 0$
$y = \sin a(x-1)$ looks like a good place to start.
$y'(2) = 0$
$y' = a\cos a(x-1)\\
y'(2) = a\cos a = 0$
$a = \frac {\pi}{2}, \frac {3\pi}{2},\cdots \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$
$y = \sin \frac {(2n+1)\pi}{2}(x-1)$
$\lambda = (\frac {(2n+1)\pi}{2})^2$ would be the eigenvalue associated with this function.

You are looking for trigonometric functions as solutions of $$-y'' = \lambda^2 y,$$ with a zero at $x=1$ and a zero of the derivative ar $x=2.$ The lowest eigenfunction is the sine of a quarter period $$y= \sin \left( (x-1) \frac{ \pi}{2} \right).$$ All others are the higher odd harmonics with a zero at $x=1$ and and extremum at $x=2.$
$$y = \sin  \left((x-1) \  ( n + \frac{1}{2}   ) \ \pi\right) $$
